# Time Complexity : Continuously summing the digits of a number until a single digit result

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am given a number N. Keep summing the digits until a single digit result.
e.g 35252 ==> 17 ==> 8
I have written the following code :

```
int digitSum(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int digit;

    while(n)
    {
        digit = n%10;
        n = n/10;
        sum += digit;
    }

    if(sum > 9)
        return digitSum(sum);
    else
        return sum;
}
```

Coming to the time complexity : 
I am given the range for N as 0 <= N <= 10^9.

In worst case, with all 9s, the recursion will go max twice and I will get  O(loglogn)

In best case, with single digit N, complexity will be O(1)

What will be the average complexity? I mean, what will be the complexity if N can be any number with no range defined.

Comment: It seems to me that the while loop has O(log(N)) complexity. It will be the leading order term.

Answer (score 3):

First, your analysis is wrong, the time complexity is not O(loglogn) for worst case, it's `O(logn)`, with the following recursive formula:

```
T(n) = logn + T(log(n) * AVG(digits)) = logn + T(9*logn)
T(1) = 1
```

Now, we can show that the above is in `O(logn)`, using induction with the induction hypothesis of: `T(n) <= 2logn`

```
T(n+1) = log(n+1) + T(9logn) <= (i.h) log(n+1) + 2*log(9log(n)) =
       = log(n+1) + 2log(9) + 2loglog(n) < 2log(n)
```

Showing it is `Omega(log(n))` is pretty trivial, with the observation that `T(n) >= 0` for all `n`.

---

Regarding the question at hand, what is the average time complexity, let's denote the average case complexity with `G(n)`, and let's assume `n` is uniformly distributed (if it's not - that will change the analysis, and the outcome might be different).

```
G(N) = lim{N->infinity} sum{i=1 to N} T(n)/N =
     = lim{N->infinity} T(1) / N + T(2) / N + ... + T(N) / N
     = lim{N->infinity} 1/N (T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(N))
     < lim{N->infinity} 1/N (2log(1) + 2log(2) + ... + 2log(N)) 
     = lim{N->inifnity} 2/N (log(1) + ... + log(N))
     = lim{N->inifnity} 2/N (log(1 * 2 * ... * N))
     = lim{N->infinity} 2/N log(N!) 
     = lim{N->infinity} 2/N * CONST * NlogN = 2*CONST * logN
```

So, we can conclude `G(N)` is also in `O(logN)`, so the average case analysis is still logarithmic in `N`.

Comment: In `T(n) = logn + T(log(n) * AVG(digits))`, why the second `log(n)` with multiplication is coming into picture? And as I understood, `T(n) = logn +loglogn + logloglogn+.....` in general resulting in `O(logn)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Well known solution is n % 9 + (n % 9 == 0 ? 9 : 0).