# Explain why time complexity for summing digits in a number of length N is O(logN)

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity

Here is the code:

```
int sumDigits(int n) {
    int sum = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I understand this code, and that the code will take the ones place digit, add that digit to sum, and remove that digit. It keeps doing this until n is equal to 0, at which point it will return sum. Intuitively the runtime will be the number of digits in number N. But I do not understand why this time complexity is O(logN). I thought it was O(N).

Even with explanation like: 
"A number with d digits can have a value up to 10^d. If n = 10^d, then d = log n. Therefore runtime is O(logN)." does not totally click.

I follow the first part that if d is say 3, then value < 10^d == value < 1000. Meaning max value is 999 with a number of length 3, which I agree with. But after that, when they make the connection that if n = 10^d, I do not understand how 1) they knew to make that equality and 2) how this makes the complexity O(logN) rather than O(N).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time Complexity : Continuously summing the digits of a number until a single digit result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073179/time-complexity-continuously-summing-the-digits-of-a-number-until-a-single-dig)

Comment: @ChatterOne that doesn't look like a duplicate, because OP's code does not necessarily produce a single digit result

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The complexity is proportional to the number of digits. After all, if there are 2,351 digits in the number, the `while` loop will iterate 2,351 times.

So the question boils down to, "how many digits are there in `N`, asymptotically?". A number with `d` digits is between `10^(d-1)` inclusive and `10^d` exclusive. In other words, let `d` be the number of digits in `N`, and we have the inequalities `10^(d-1) <= N < 10^d`. Taking a logarithm, we have `d-1 <= log(N) < d`. (We can maintain the inequalities because logarithms are monotonic.) Adding `1` to the left inequality gives `d <= log(N) + 1`, and combining with the previous result, we have `log(N) < d <= log(N) + 1`. That is, we've upper-bounded and lower-bounded the number of digits `d` by terms that are `O(log(N))`.

The above shows that the number of digits is `O(log(N))`, or more precisely `Theta(log(N))`. The time complexity is the same since it's proportional to the number of digits.

Comment: Thank you, this explanation makes total sense to me and is more intuitive!

Comment: This is a log(10, N) since most of the time the log(n) you will see in algorithms will be referring to log(2, N).

Comment: @Baso Yes, log(N) as the number of digits is base 10. Note however that O(log_10(N)) is equivalent to O(log_2(N)) because changing the base of the logarithm is just a constant multiplicative factor. Hence, for discussing Big-O notation, generally the base of the logarithm is omitted as it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8):

You're confusing two definitions of `N` here.  Your text cites it as the number itself; your latter description treats `N` as the quantity of digits.  Yes, the algorithm is **O(digits)** complexity ... but the quantity of digits is roughly **log10(N)**, where `N` is the number.

Comment: Yes you are totally right.. I will be more careful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would recall that: log(10) = 1, and the logarithm remains less than 2 as long as N<100, log(100) = 2, and so on.

The simple rule that emerges is: Add 1 to the characteristic to get the # of digits in the number.

Or, in briefer mathematical notation, using the floor function, D = ⌊log10N⌋+1